# Effective three day split for size and aesthetics?

Tags: weightlifting, exercise, strength, strength-training

For the past year and a half I've been doing starting strength with some good results. I'm now getting married within year and want to transition to a program that focuses more on size and aesthetics rather than strength. Unfortunately all the one's that I find are more bodybuilding related and require you to work out five days a week which with a study and work routine isn't a possibility for me.

Are there any programs similar to starting strength (ie. can be performed three days a week) that are more aesthetic based or how would I go about designing one?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "size and aesthetics"?  You want bulk?  Definition?  Both?  Where are you now relative to your goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very common 3-day split is push/pull/legs. If you google it there are a million different variations. Find one you like and tweak it to fit you as time goes on.

Alternatively you could do a more "old school" bb'er routine like chest/tris, back/bis, shoulders/legs.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I don't bodybuild and have not tried these.

### Boring But Big

The [5/3/1 variant called Boring But Big](http://www.t-nation.com/free_online_article/most_recent/the_boring_but_big_3month_challenge) gets good press. The idea is to do 5 sets of 10 on one major lift each day, then finish the workout with assistance lifts.

### Kilgore/Hartman/Lascek's Novice Mass-Gain

Dr. Lon Kilgore (co-author of Starting Strength), Dr. Michael Hartman, and Justin Lascek of 70s Big present [a novice mass-gain progression](http://www.reddit.com/r/Fitness/comments/18eh63/a_beginner_mass_gain_routine_from/) in their book FIT. It recommends 3 sets of 10 on multiple versions of the major lifts as well as a small number of bodybuilding-specific exercises. The authors are well-respected in the S&C community, so I give this program weight.

- **Monday**: squat, calf raise, *overhead press*, lat pulldown, shrugs
- **Wednesday**: *bench press*, rows, dips, deadlift, weighted crunch
- **Friday**: front squat, back extension, *curls*, french press, chin-ups

The exercises in italics alternate between barbell and dumbbell versions each week. Dips and chin-ups are done to failure if one cannot get 10 full reps, and use added weight if one can do more than 10 in a set. Deadlifts only get 1 set, not 3, at the heaviest weight.

### GreySkull Linear Progression

You could also look into [GreySkull LP](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/9699/1771): a novice progression, similar to Starting Strength but with more of a focus on upper-body mass gain and aesthetics.

Comment: Are they not more strength orientated though?

Comment: This is a much better answer than the accepted "google it".